# The phase portrait of a second order of nonlinear system using matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I have the following system 
$$
\ddot{x} + 0.6\dot{x} + 3x + x^{2} = 0
$$

In the [book](http://www.amazon.ca/Applied-Nonlinear-Control-Jean-Jacques-Slotine/dp/0130408905) I'm reading, the phase portrait of the nonlinear system for the aforementioned equation is

[image]

I would like to get same result in Matlab. This is what I did

```
function output = F(t, x)

output = [ x(2);
          -0.6*x(2) - 3*x(1) - x(1)^2];

end
```

and this is the main function

```
clear all
clc
   x0 = 1;
xdot0 = 1;
t = 0:0.01:10;
X0    = [x0, xdot0];

[T X] = ode45(@F, t, X0);


figure(1)
clf
plot(X(:,1), X(:,2))
title('The Phase Portrait of a nonlinear system');
xlabel('x');
ylabel('xdot');
```

I'm not getting same result. My question is how can I modify the code to get same result?

---

Edit:
Now it is working with the following code.

```
function output = F(t, x)

output = [ x(2);
          -0.6*x(2) - 3.*x(1) - x(1)^2];

end
```

The main.m

```
t = 0:0.1:8;
X0    = [-3, 4.5];
[T X] = ode45(@F, t, X0);


figure(1)
clf

plot(X(:,1), X(:,2))
title('The Phase Portrait of a nonlinear system');
xlabel('x');
ylabel('xdot');
axis([-9 9 -10 10])
grid on

hold on
X0    = [4, 8];
[T X] = ode45(@F, t, X0);
plot(X(:,1), X(:,2))

hold on
X0    = [-1, 2];
[T X] = ode45(@F, t, X0);
plot(X(:,1), X(:,2))

hold on
X0    = [-7, 6];
[T X] = ode45(@F, t, X0);
plot(X(:,1), X(:,2))

hold on
X0    = [-8, 5];
[T X] = ode45(@F, t, X0);
plot(X(:,1), X(:,2))

hold on
X0    = [-5.5, 9];
[T X] = ode45(@F, t, X0);
plot(X(:,1), X(:,2))

hold on
X0    = [-2.5, 8];
[T X] = ode45(@F, t, X0);
plot(X(:,1), X(:,2))
```

Comment: So, can you shed more light on what's wrong with your Matlab code? As far as I see, you've plotted one single trajectory. And no doubts that it won't look like the picture you've attached.

Comment: @Evgeny, I've added the rest of the initial values.

Comment: Can you be more precious about what is "the same result" for you? The plot from you book is much more than just a collection of phase trajectories. Also, minor comments to your Matlab code: 1) you don't have to write "hold on" each time you plot another trajectory, only first call affects axes state; 2) initial values can be stored in array, so you might iterate through them in loop.